# Barplot (gráfico de barras) de variável numérica versus categórica no R

Tags: r

Como plotar um gráfico de barras no R em que no `eixo x` tenho uma variável categórica (com 4 categorias: frequente, as vezes, raro, nunca) e no `eixo y` a média de uma variável numérica (Y=0:13)? Como faço para inserir a legenda acima das barras?

Abaixo um exemplo da tabela de cruzamento da variável categórica com a numérica. Nas colunas "frequente", "as vezes", "raro" e "nunca" estão o número de indivíduos que responderam uma dessas quatro opções e a pontuação de Y (0:13).

```
  Y        Frequente  As vezes   Raro    Nunca
  0          86        70        111       69
  1         227       181        246      149
  2         341       254        417      197
  3         418       298        501      275
  4         396       316        541      257
  5         458       310        564      307
  6         387       273        562      246
  7         352       212        518      228
  8         247       167        401      207
  9         173       118        278      131
  10         88        54        140       61
  11         35        19         74       27
  12          9         7         31        8
  13          2         0          3        0
```

A informação que deve ter no gráfico de barras é: qual é a média de Y para os indivíduos que responderam: frequente, raro, as vezes e nunca.

Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dados %>%
  gather(intensidade, qtd, -Y) %>%
  group_by(intensidade) %>%
  summarise(media = weighted.mean(Y, qtd)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = intensidade, y = media)) + geom_col()
```

Considerando que dados é um data.frame da mesma forma que você postou.
Não esqueça de instalar os pacotes antes de usar. Da pra instalar todos juntos usando `install.packages('tidyverse')`.

O gráfico gerado é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não consegui rodar - Erro: Invalid column specification - Você poderia detalhar o que atribuiu a "intensidade" e "qtd", por favor?

Comment: intensidade e quantidade são apenas nomes para as colunas que são criadas... poste o resultado de dput(dados) para que a gente possa olhar exatamente como está a sua base. Meu chute que não existe nenhuma coluna chamada Y...

Comment: consegui!! Valeu!